# Airflow 2.0 how to backfill from command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

Does anyone know how to backfill from command in Airflow 2.0? the below command worked for me when I used Airflow 1.0, but since upgrading to 2.0 there have been some issues with subqueries.

Command for Airflow composer 1.0

```
gcloud composer environments run leo-stage-bi --location=europe-west1 backfill -- regulatory_spain_daily -t "regulatory_spain_ru*" -s 20211201 -e 20220119 --reset_dagruns --ignore_dependencies
```

Comment: Can you specify what issues?

Comment: I like to know how to execute backfill command on composer 2.0, this is my question

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is not with Composer but you simply use wrong Airflow syntax.

In Airflow<2.0.0:

```
airflow backfill -s START_DATE -e END_DATE dag_id
```

In Airflow>=2.0.0:

```
airflow dags backfill --start-date START_DATE --end-date END_DATE dag_id
```

(You can still use `-s` and `-e` if you prefer)

You should run:

```
gcloud composer environments run leo-stage-bi --location=europe-west1 dags backfill -- regulatory_spain_daily -t "regulatory_spain_ru*" --start-date 20211201 --end-date 20220119 --reset_dagruns --ignore_dependencies
```